# Grasp matrix implementation

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, manipulator, stability

I've majorly followed [Dex-net](https://github.com/BerkeleyAutomation/dex-net/blob/cccf93319095374b0eefc24b8b6cd40bc23966d2/src/dexnet/grasping/quality.py#L182) implementation to calculate a grasp matrix (G) to compute other grasp quality metrics (e.g., Ferrari Canny L1 metric or smallest singular value of G).

Based on my understanding after searching documents and papers, grasp matrix is a 6xM matrix that transforms forces applied on contact points to the wrench space (Hence, it does not really care about absolute magnitude of applied forces). However, the implementation in the Dex-net code base seems to directly use applied forces and torques to build their matrix, which makes me confused.

I'm currently trying to build a grasp matrix for 2 soft-finger gripper. I hope someone can give me a **concrete explanation or reference** I can look up.